# Go: A function that would consume maps with different types of values

Tags: go

In my code, I need a function that would return an ordered slice of keys from a map.

```
m1 := make(map[string]string)
m2 := make(map[string]int)
```

And now I need to call a function passing both types of maps:

```
keys1 := sortedKeys(m1)
keys2 := sortedKeys(m1)
```

**Problem**: I have to write two functions because the function should consume maps of two different types. At the same time, the body of the function will be the same in both cases.

**Question:** How can I use a single implementation for two maps? Or is there any other way of solving the problem in an elegant way?

My first idea was to use `map[string]interface{}` as an argument type, but you can't assign neither `map[string]string`, nor `map[string]int` to it.

**My code:**

```
func sortedKeys(m map[string]string) []string {
    var keys []string
    for key := range m {
        keys = append(keys, key)
    }
    sort.Strings(keys)
    return keys
}
```

I would have to repeat the same code but for `map[string]int`.

Comment: Write two functions. It is really that simple. You might even write three functions. Before starting the fourth version: Consider switching to reflection.

Comment: You could use `func sortedKeys(m interface{}) []string` to be able to pass in both `map[string]string` and `map[string]int`, then inside you'd use reflection to get the keys.

Comment: Why voting down? Am I not clear on what I want to achieve?

Comment: @Volker of course it is simple, but still it is 8 lines of code, would be great if I could reuse it.

Comment: @SashaShpota maybe it would be great but it's just not possible. In essence you seem to be asking whether or not it's possible to specify only "half the type", e.g. `map[string]<T>`, or `map[string]<string|int>`, then write a function that takes such a type, and then be able to pass to it values of types like `map[string]string` and `map[string]int`. In Go this is simply not possible, either write two functions or use `interface{}` and reflection.

Comment: @mkopriva thanks! "Not possible" is also a valid answer :) I asked this question because I am not experienced in Go and was looking for a better solution.

Comment: "but still it is 8 lines of code". That is a joke, right? 8 lines of trivial code is literally nothing. Just write it twice.

Comment: It's not possible in Go because Go does not support generics. It's considered acceptable to repeat 8 lines of code.

Comment: I have provided a solution which works. Please stop considering Go without generics as handicapped. 

Hope the solutions helps (because it definitely works)

Please add extra checks and minor optimizations for making it production codebase

Comment: @SashaShpota "would be great if I could reuse it." you really should train yourself out of this mindset if you intend to use go.

Comment: @Masklinn : I tend to disagree to this. Rather than saying "Not Possible" and repeat the code, we should provide the solution with a condition to use it only when multiple types need to be supported. Also, this will ensure the developer learns more about how reflections work in Go.

Answer (score 3):

You can use interface{} and use reflection for achieving this.

You can write two functions for the same but it is just not scalable, say, you are supporting string and int now but you wish to support int64, float64, bool or struct in the future. Having a common function using map[string]interface{} and using reflection is the way to go.

Suggested Code :

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

func main() {
    m1 := make(map[string]string)
    m2 := make(map[string]int)

    m1["a"] = "b"
    m1["b"] = "c"

    m2["a"] = 1
    m2["b"] = 2

    fmt.Println(sortedKeys(m1))
    fmt.Println(sortedKeys(m2))
}

// Returns slice of values in the type which is sent to it
func sortedKeys(m interface{}) interface{} {

    if m == nil {
       return nil
    }

    if reflect.TypeOf(m).Kind() != reflect.Map {
        return nil
    }

    mapIter := reflect.ValueOf(m).MapRange()
    mapVal := reflect.ValueOf(m).Interface()

    typ := reflect.TypeOf(mapVal).Elem()
    outputSlice := reflect.MakeSlice(reflect.SliceOf(typ), 0, 0)


    for mapIter.Next() {
       outputSlice = reflect.Append(outputSlice, mapIter.Value())
    }


    return outputSlice.Interface()


}
```

Output :

[b c]

[1 2]

https://play.golang.org/p/2fkpydH9idG

Comment: @shasha-shpota : Can you let me know if this solution worked for you ? If yes, can you accept this as a correct answer. Thank you.